# How can I find the C++ code for the R package bsts?

Tags: c++, r

Consider fitting a Student-t local level model in R using the `bsts` package:

```
library(bsts)
y <- rnorm(100)
ss <- AddLocalLevel(list(), y)
mod <- bsts(y, state.specification = ss, family='student', niter=500)
```

After the model is fitted, the object `mod` has attributes `mod$sigma.level` and `mod$observation.df` that each contain `niter=500` draws of the variance and degrees of freedom for the observation equation, respectively.

Could someone please help me locate the source code that generates the 500 draws for `mod$sigma.level` and `mod$observation.df`? It seems to be hidden away in C++ code, but I cannot find it in the package archive on CRAN. Any guidance would be appreciated - you do not need to know anything about this specific model.

Comment: Have you tried looking at https://github.com/cran/bsts/blob/master/src/bsts.cc or looking at https://github.com/cran/bsts/tree/master/src?

Comment: @Mr.Rlover Yes I have, but I can't find the part of the code that I am looking for. For example, bsts.cc refers to other files (e.g. Models/StateSpace/StateSpaceModelBase.hpp) that look like they might be helpful, but which I cannot locate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mr.Rlover points out, the source code is listed [here](https://github.com/cran/bsts/blob/master/src/bsts.cc#L40). If you trace it through, you'll find that the random number generator comes from a C++ singleton class called RNG, defined in the BOOM library, which is included in the `bsts` C++ code, and appears to have been written by the same author. The RNG class is defined [here](https://github.com/cran/Boom/blob/95e9c89edc4c9d3319686f8e4bfed10ba17a26df/inst/include/distributions/rng.hpp#L27) in the BOOM library's github page. If you look around this repo, you will find a lot of the C++ functions called in `bsts`.

If you read the definition for RNG, then the random number generator seems ultimately to depend on the C++ standard library's implementation of the Mersenne Twister algorithm using 64 bit numbers and a state size of 19937 bits, `std::mt19937_64`. You can find out more about this, including implementation details, [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mt19937_64/)

Comment: Thanks! The BOOM library’s Github page has everything. How did you trace it back to there?